# Help configuring the democracy pallet and referenda proposal

Tags: pallet, democracy, configuration, config

This is regarding the democracy pallet and referenda proposal:

When submitting the proposal, a deposit needs to be defined where the MinimumDeposit config can be used to set the minimum amount to be deposited. Although we've set it inside our democracy config, Subscan shows that the deposit is of value 0. Can someone point out to the correct configuration for the minimum deposit?

[image: Subscan screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it is in the referenda config:

```rust
/// The **minimum** amount to be used as a deposit for a public referendum proposal.
#[pallet::constant]
type SubmissionDeposit: Get<BalanceOf<Self, I>>;
```

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/1cbb2ef4f2bc7486a60a5ece409525ae46bce3b6/frame/referenda/src/lib.rs#L190-L192

Comment: It is confirmed that `SubmissionDeposit` is and was always set to 1 unit at the time of this proposal submission

Comment: And you are still seeing 0 in the Subscan UI? If so, can you provide the link to the page where you see 0?

Comment: No, now the problem is sloved. Seems more like subscan issue